# How to get a long term OAuth Token for New release

Tags: spotify

I am working for a course work that needs to console the new release albums, and I try to get OAuth Token in the API console, However it can only run short time, after half hour it does work.
How to gain a long term OAuth Token for it ?

Answer (score 1):

The access tokens issued by the Spotify Web API have an expiration time of 1 hour. If you implement the [Authorization Code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow) you will get an additional `refresh_token` that you can use to obtain a new access token when the current one expires.

I recommend you to read the [Spotify Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) to get an overview of the OAuth 2.0 authorization framework, and also the [beginner's tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/) that shows how to implement the authorization code flow step by step.